# call ejb from spring boot which is on weblogic server

Tags: spring-boot, ejb, weblogic12c

As per our application I need to call ejb from our spring boot application. But currently I am not exact reference to start with.

Ejb's are currently in jar file which I have already integrated through pom. But I am not getting any reference to call it from my  appplication

Can anyone please guide me or give a reference.

Comment: To clarify: do you want to call a remote EJB or is the EJB class inside your Spring Boot app?

Comment: @Simon Remote EJB, and that service present in jar which I have integrated through pom